# Azure Synapse Analytics tutorial: SQL syntax error "Parse error at line: 5, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'."

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to get all Monday between 2 dates and for this created stored procedure which is working fine in SQL (on Prim) but when I try the same in Azure Synapse, I get this error:

> "Parse error at line: 5, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'."

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Staffing].[GetWeekDays]
    @StartDate date, 
    @EndDate date
AS
BEGIN
    WITH T0 AS 
    (
        SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1)) AS tmp(N)
    ), T1 AS 
    (
        SELECT N = 1 
        FROM T0 AS a 
        CROSS JOIN T0 AS b
    ), T2 AS 
    (
        SELECT N = 1 
        FROM T1 AS a 
        CROSS JOIN T1 AS b
    ), T3 AS 
    (
        SELECT N = 1 
        FROM T2 AS a 
        CROSS JOIN T2 AS b
    ), T4 AS 
    (
        SELECT N = 1 
        FROM T3 AS a 
        CROSS JOIN T3 AS b
    ), T5 AS   
    (
        SELECT N = 1  
        FROM T4 AS a 
        CROSS JOIN T4 AS b
    ), Tally AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP 500000 
            [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @StartDate) 
        FROM T5
    )
    SELECT [Date]
    FROM Tally
    WHERE [Date] <= @EndDate and  [Date] >= @StartDate 
      AND DATENAME (dw, [Date]) = 'Monday'
      AND YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
END
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to do **date calculations** the best thing you could do here would be to use a date dimension.  Then your query would be a simple `SELECT` with a `Between` operator
rather than an over-complicated and hard to maintain proc.  A simple example:

```
SELECT calendarDate
FROM calendar.main
WHERE calendarDate Between @StartDate And @EndDate
  AND datenameDay = 'Monday';
```

This would then make other date calculations easier.  For example you could add public holidays to it or 'how many working days between ...' or 'tell me all leap years'.  As the date dimension will likely be small you could set the distribution to `REPLICATE` to make sure it is copied to all distributions in your Synapse dedicated SQL pool.

Answer (score -2):

You got to place a ";" semicolon before with clause.

Comment: Done like this but still same issue
;WITH 
T0 AS (SELECT N  FROM (VALUES (1),(1)) AS tmp(N))

Comment: Where are you trying to build this? in Azure SQL DB? or in some other RDBMS? I just tried building this in my Sample Azure SQL DB and it worked fine, even without ";".

Comment: I am trying it in Azure Synapse. If its working at Azure SQL DB then it should work at Synapse as well but its not working at my end

Comment: When it comes to CTE , Azure synapse have some limitations. I think it will not allow using T0 in definition of T1 and so on as you are doing. It is possible in on-prim and Azure SQL DB. Check this (See the last example) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#features-and-limitations-of-common-table-expressions-in--and-

Comment: I have tried this 

WITH CTE(datelist) AS (
      SELECT '07/08/2021'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day,1,datelist) FROM CTE
      WHERE datelist<='07/28/2021'
)
SELECT datelist as 'List of Mondays'
FROM CTE
WHERE DATENAME(weekday ,datelist) IN ('Monday');

but getting error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "datelist" of recursive query "CTE"."